# How to use two generic parameters in function?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I use this function:

```
bind<T, K extends keyof T>(
    data: T[],
    bindedData: T[],
    key: K,
    newKey: string
  ) {
}
```

How can I use two generic parameters, I tried:

```
bind<T, K extends keyof T>, <B, KB extends keyof B>(){}
```

Comment: did you try `let fn = <T, U>(arg1: T, arg2: U) => 42`?

Comment: You already have two generic parameters, `T` and `K`. If you want four that's fine, but they all go within one set of `<>`: `<T, K extends keyof T, B, KB extends keyof B>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like this

```
function bind<T, K extends keyof T, B, KB extends keyof B>(){}
```

Comment: And how to use?

Comment: @OPV No idea what you mean, but you can call it like this `bind(["s"], ["s"], 1, "s")`